# How to show entire multi-line text in a popup menu after first click

Tags: java, swing

I am having some trouble with popup menu and multi-line text. When the popup menu is displayed for the first time, only the first line is visible. Here is how it looks like after first click

[image: Popup menu after first click]

and after second click

[image]

**What should I do to make it to show the whole text after the first click?**

I tried validating, invalidating, revalidating and repainting various components. I even tried to [pack the ancestor window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231941/2035618) (at that time the content of the popup menu was dynamic and I thought that that was causing the problem). It behaves the same way if I use multi-line JLabel (using html content).

**Edit: More research**

Preferred size of the text component is probably wrong. Before the popup menu is displayed for the first time, the preferred height is 21. After it is displayed it is 51. So it is displayed based on wrong preferred size. **Is there some way to calculate the preferred size it in advance?**

I boiled the problem down to following minimal example:

```
public class PopupMenuFail extends JFrame {

    public PopupMenuFail() {
        final JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
        text.setText("Some text long enough to be split into several lines.");
        text.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 1000)); // limit the width

        final JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        popupMenu.add(text);

        final JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setAction(new AbstractAction("Click me") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                popupMenu.show(button, 0, button.getHeight());
            }
        });
        add(button);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new PopupMenuFail();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am running a 64-bit linux,

```
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.72-b04, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply set a default minimum size to your JPopupMenu using `popupMenu.setPopupSize(500, 500)` for example and this would works.

However, if you are trying to create a menu, you should check `JMenu` and `JMenuItem`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html

Comment: I do not know the exact content in advance. I could use some fixed size but it would be best if the popup could be resized to fit the content exactly. I do not want a menu, I am just abusing the popup's ability to disapear after clicking anywhere else.

Comment: pack() with success for HeavyWeight JPopup,